# sudo and login slow after LDAP server crashed

Tags: sudo, ldap, openldap

I'm working with 3 servers, 1 acting as an `LDAP` server and the other two connecting with clients.  The `LDAP` server has crashed, and I'm able to log in to the other two with local accounts, but when doing `sudo` or `ssh` they take a while to respond, sometimes over a minute.  Both servers are doing this so it seems pretty likely to be an `LDAP` issue.

I've uninstalled `ldap-auth-client` and `nscd` but haven't had any effect.

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this or remove ldap client properly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have edited /etc/nsswitch.conf when you set up your LDAP client computers?  In the fields marked passwd, group, and shadow, perhaps you have "ldap compat"?  Try removing "ldap".

This will prevent it from using LDAP to look-up passwd, group, or shadow values.  I guess if you've completely removed the LDAP servers, you should also delete any instance of "ldap" in this file.